# Whats a good way to specify links and filepaths in jsps?

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl

Wanted to know how to specify links and jsp filepaths in jsps. Is it better to specify them on the jsp itself or if its better to keep them all in a constants file so that it is easier to change things if the path to a jsp changes or the url of a link changes.

By the way I also use the Struts2 framework and JSTL tags on my pages.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what you mean by the flexibility, but to include the jsp S2 provides a very clean and efficient way to includes one JSP in another JSP.

```
<s:include value="myJsp.jsp" />
```

it will also provides the way to pass any additional parameters.For details refer to the document for details

- [S2 Include tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/include.html)

For specifying the links you can use `<s:url>` tag.`%{url}` will be evaluated to the url defined with the s:url tag. On the Welcome and HelloWorld pages, we use two different Struts tags to create links. We create

- Resource links
- Direct links, and
- Links with parameters.

For details refer to the documentation in details

1. [S2 URL tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/url.html)
2. [using-tags](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/using-tags.html)

There are other way to include jsp in more flexible way like including the jsp at run time based on the JSP value being set from the action , but without any further information about your use case its hard to suggest.